# Render chart only once with multiple events : Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

So what I have is a chart in which I have events function which loads data for multiple sets.

suppose I have data of 3000 points. The first data set renders the first 1000 points and after that second data set renders 2000 points.

for which I am calling my 'events' function .

but the problem arises that after showing the first 1000 set of data. The chart starts from the begining. 
I don't want that.

That's why I need a solution so that my Highchart's chart render only once and the event function loads continuously.

Here's a snip of my Highchart's js

```
Highcharts.chart("chartcontainer", { // make thsi chart load only once.
                chart: {
                    type: 'line',
                    animation: Highcharts.svg, // don't animate in old IE
                    marginRight: 10,


//Load this event function as the data updates
 events: {
                        load: function() {

                            var series = this.series[0],
                                chart = this;

                            setInterval(function() {

                      //some logic regarding the chart
                       //..
                        v = {
                                                y: y,
                                                x: x
                                            };

                    console.log("V value", v);
                    series.addSeries(v, false, true);
                    counter++;
                    localcounter++;                                 
                }   else
                {

                    oldcounter=counter;
                    flagToreload=1;
                                    }
                            }, 1000/130);

                            setInterval(function() {
                                chart.redraw(false);
                            }, 100);
                        }
                    }
                },

                time: {
                    useUTC: false
                },

                title: {
                    text: 'Live random data'
                },
                xAxis: {

                    type: 'Value',

                    gridLineWidth: 1

                },
                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: 'Value'
                    },
                    plotLines: [{
                        value: 0,
                        width: 1,
                        color: '#808080'
                    }],
                    gridLineWidth: 1
                },
                tooltip: {
                    headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br/>',
                    pointFormat: '{point.x:%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S}<br/>{point.y:.2f}'
                },
                exporting: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                series: [{
                    animation: false,
                    name: 'Random data',
                    data: (function() {
                        // generate an array of random data
                        var data = [],
                            time = counter,
                            i;

                        for (i = -1000; i <= 0; i += 1) {
                            data.push([
                                counter,
                                null
                        ]);


                        }
                        return data;
                    }())
                }]
            });
```

Comment: Hi @Abnit Chauhan, Could you reproduce the problem in some online code editor? You can start from: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/ The code that you have provided is not valid.

Comment: in simple words. I want to define the Highchart only once. and render its line continuously. suppose I have two different arrays. after the first array is displayed. I want the second array to be displayed in continuation of that. but right now the second array data starts from zero again. @ppotaczek

Comment: PS: define chart only once and update its internal data everytime. @ppotaczek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

- `addPoint` method:

---

```
chart: {
    events: {
        load: function() {
            var newData,
                chart = this,
                series = chart.series[0];

            setInterval(function() {
                newData = getRandomData();

                newData.forEach(function(el) {
                    series.addPoint(el, false);
                });

                chart.redraw();

            }, 2000);
        }
    }
}
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/2a8qswhf/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#addPoint

---

- `setData` method:

---

```
chart: {
    events: {
        load: function() {
            var newData,
                chart = this,
                combinedData,
                series = chart.series[0];

            setInterval(function() {
                newData = getRandomData();

                combinedData = series.userOptions.data.concat(newData);

                series.setData(combinedData);
            }, 2000);
        }
    }
}
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/Lmsk8yw9/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#setData